# How to convert text label to integer?

Tags: swift2, uitableview

What is the right way to convert a text label to an integer in Swift 2? The following keeps throwing an error `Fix-It Insert ";"`.

```
let deptid = (Int)myCell?.deptid.text
```

Comment: Please read the [Basics](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html)   chapter in the Swift Language Guide.

Comment: PS: It's `Int(myCell?.deptid.text)`, but you should handle the case if the text is not numeric.

Comment: The error went away but the value returned is nil. Although the actual value is "100.00". Any ideas?

Comment: Basically, Int("100.00") produces a nil.

Comment: Strictly spoken `100.00` is not an integer

Comment: Yes. Float() will work with integers as well so I should just go with Float().

Comment: Rather use `Double`. It's the default floating point type in Swift.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot cast an optional `String` to `Int`. You should use the `Int` initializer instead, like this

Here's the code

```
if let text = myCell.deptid?.text, num = Int(text) {
    print(num)
}
```

Comment: Even if you could, the compiler doesn't like the ObjC casting style ;-)